# Pandas - create new column with replaced values while keeping original column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, data-processing

I'm a newbie to python so please bear with me. I have a data frame where I want to replace values for specific strings. Below is my starting df (df_train):

```
       A    B     C     D
0     .5   Ex    Ex    Po
1     35   Gd    TA    Gd
2     52   TA    Fa    Ex
3     47   Bd    Po    Gd
```

I can easily replace the values I'd like and create a new df(df_train_scaled), per below:

```
df_train_scaled = df_train.replace(['Ex','Gd','TA','Fa','Po'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

I'm curious if I should do this and go to a new df(df_train_scaled) to continue data pre-processing before modeling, or if I should create a new column in the same df (df_train). Regardless of the answer, I do want to figure out how to add a new column to the same df with the replaced values. Output below:

```
       A    B   B_new  C   C_new   D   D_new
0     .5   Ex     5    Ex     5    Po    1
1     35   Gd     4    TA     3    Gd    4
2     52   TA     3    Fa     2    Ex    5
3     47   Gd     4    Po     1    Gd    4
```

If I do this, I can experiment to see if my ordinal, or scaled, variables will perform better in my modeling efforts. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply append two tables together:

```
df_train_scaled = df_train.iloc[:,1:].replace(['Ex','Gd','TA','Fa','Po'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
df_train_scaled.columns = [x + "_new" for x in df_train_scaled.columns]
pd.concat([df_train, df_train_scaled], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace` + `concat`

```
d=dict(zip(['Ex','Gd','TA','Fa','Po'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
df.replace(d)
Out[848]: 
      A   B  C  D
0   0.5   5  5  1
1  35.0   4  3  4
2  52.0   3  2  5
3  47.0  Bd  1  4
pd.concat([df,df.iloc[:,1:].replace(d).add_suffix('_New')],1).sort_index(1)
Out[849]: 
      A     B B_New   C  C_New   D  D_New
0   0.5     Ex     5  Ex      5  Po      1
1  35.0     Gd     4  TA      3  Gd      4
2  52.0     TA     3  Fa      2  Ex      5
3  47.0     Bd    Bd  Po      1  Gd      4
```